# Showing a $2$-dim function is measurable

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Give the deﬁnition of the sigma-algebra $B_2$ of Borel measurable sets in $\mathbb R^2$.

If $\mathbb G$ is the collection of all open subsets off $\mathbb R^2$, then the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathbb G$ is the Borel sigma-algebra $B_2$.

Prove that the following two functions $φ, ψ: \mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R$ deﬁned by
$φ (x,y) = x$ and
$ψ (x,y) = x+y$
are measurable with respect to $(\mathbb R^2,B_2)$.

---

With the first function I had a go and I am struggling with the second. So we need to prove that $Y=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x>a\} \in  B_2$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$.

$a>0$: If $x \le 0$ then it wouldn't make sense so $x>0$ so $x>a$ so $Y=(a, \infty) \times \mathbb R$ which is an open set so it is Borel.

$a=0$: If $x \le 0$, it wouldn't make sense so $x>0$ and $x>a=0$ so $Y=( a, \infty ) \times \mathbb R$ which is open so it is Borel.

$a<0$: Let $-b=a$ where $b>0$ so $x>-b$. If $x \ge 0$ then it holds, so far we have $Y=[0, \infty)$. If $x<0$, then $x>-b$ but no more than $0$ so $(-b,0)$ so $Y=(a, \infty) \times \mathbb R$ which is open so Borel.

I am not sure what to say about the bounds of $y$. I am guessing it can be anything since it does not appear on the equation?

Is this correct though?

Comment: Say if we cant mention anything about them being continuous, would my working for the first function be correct? Please reply someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously get, that continuity implies measurability. In particular the functions you are continous and hence measurable.

Comment: So I didn't have to do any working out?